# Microsoft access validation

Tags: database, validation, ms-access, alphanumeric

I need to only allow **only** alphanumeric characters to be entered into a field. The data type is 'Short Text'.

**What is the 'Validation Rule' using the expression builder?**

Comment: Add what you have tried

Comment: I just have no clue where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What language you are using?

Comment: Its just Microsoft Access 2013

Answer (score 1):

You can find lots of useful examples for validation rules here:
http://allenbrowne.com/ValidationRule.html

In your case -

**Digits and letters only**

```
Is Null OR Not Like "*[!((a-z) or (0-9))]*"
```

Accepts A to Z and 0 to 9, but no punctuation or other characters.